# Create SubViews Programmatically and then add TapGesture For Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a beginner with PHP Background.
I want to create subviews using `FOR` loop and then detect which subview was tapped and then perform some action.
So far i have successfully implemented creating subviews using this code:

Inside `-(IBAction)ADD:(id)sender{`

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];

float x=0;
float y=0;
float w = 160.0; //width of a box
float h = 100.0; //height of a box
int num = 0;
int totalBoxes = 20;
BOOL yChanged = false; //this is to know if a new line to be added by incrementing y
NSTimeInterval delayTime = 0.1; //for delaying the animation a bit
for(int i=0; i<=totalBoxes; i++){
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, w, h)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    view.alpha = 0.0; //initially setting this view to alpha=0 for fadeIn effect
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [scrollview addSubview:view];
    delayTime += 0.1; //for delaying the animation a bit
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                    delay: delayTime
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                    animations:^{view.alpha=1.0;}
                    completion:nil]; //performing block animation
    //this is all for detecting where to add the next box...
    if(yChanged){
        num = 1;
        yChanged = false;
    } else {
        num ++;
    }

    x += w+1;
    if(num >= 2){
        y += h+1;
        yChanged = true;
        x = 0;
    }
}
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, (totalBoxes/2)*h);
```

Now, i have no clue where to add the Tap Gesture.
All i want is that when a box is Tapped once, i get to know what box was Tapped so that i can pull some info out of it and show it on the new subview (i.e. sliding all the boxes off the screen and then show a new view where i will show contents taken from the Tapped Box. This is more like a UITableView, but i don't want to use that due to my design needs.)

Any ideas? Much appreciated, thank you!

******UPDATE******
As per `Owen Hartnett` Answer:

I added the following code just before the `[scrollview addSubview:view];`:

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
[playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor darkTextColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playButton setEnabled:YES];
[playButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[playButton addTarget: view
                   action:@selector()
         forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

[view addSubview:playButton];
```

Now, i am confused on how to add action specifically for this button inside the `action:@selector()` ?
So that each button will have unique actions to perform.
Please advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this.  Your views are essentially buttons, so you could easily add a clear (invisible) button over each view that would respond to your taps.  Then you could use the tag property of the UIButton to know which button actually got the tap. The advantage is that the buttons stay with the view.  If you feel you really must add the tap gesture, then just add it right anytime after you create your view.  Note that you'll have either 20 gesture recognizers or 20 buttons.  Personally, I think the buttons are easier to manage.

Comment: thank you, can you please check my update, i added the button code but don't know how to add action into it.

Comment: You need to add another method to your code, which returns void, and has a single parameter, i.e. -(void) myButtonTapped:(id) sender { }, where you typecast sender to a UIButton *. Then change "@selector()" to "@selector(myButtonTapped:)"

Comment: You can use the tag property to find out which button is selected (on creation, assign a different number to each tag). Or you can create a different tapped method for each button.

Comment: adding button approach worked! I will update my question and add the working code shortly for others benefit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code right after adding the new view as subview to the scrollview

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = view.frame;
//tag should be > 0
button.tag = i+1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scrollview addSubview:button];
```

And of course add this function to your controller:

```
-(void)scrollButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSInteger scrollViewIndex = sender.tag-1;
}
```

Comment: Just read your update to the question. Make sure to add the view first and then the button, so that the (invisible) buttons are on top of the views.